# Can't display button after every post

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

So I'm trying to display a delete button after every post. Here's my issue. For some reason it will never show, no matter what I do. Here's my code to display the post

```
<?php while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     echo $post = $row['post_content'].'-'.$row['post_date']."<hr>";
}
?>
```

And for the delete button

```
<input name="Submit2" type="button" class="button" onclick="javascript:location.href='delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>';" value="&laquo; Back" />
```

I'm trying to pass in the `ID` from the result,so I'd assume that the code has to be in somewhere in `while` section. Any help would be great.

Comment: Put the `<input ...`'s in the loop.

Comment: The result of setting $post will be just TRUE. Remove "$post =" from your echo or echo $post as new line.

Comment: But I'd be mixing php with HTML. Wouldn't I have to escape it? @LozCheroneツ

Comment: Is this anyway related with my issue? Or is it a suggestion? @hellcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `<input ...` in the loop.

If its an issue with syntax the you simply need to escape dependent on which quotes you define the string with.

```
<?php 
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
     echo $row['post_content'].' - '.$row['post_date'].'
     <input name="Submit2" type="button" class="button" onclick="javascript:location.href=\'delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'\';" value="&laquo; Back" />
     <hr>';
}
?>
```

or

```
<?php while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):?>
    <?php echo $row['post_content'].' - '.$row['post_date']; ?> 
    <input name="Submit2" type="button" class="button" onclick="javascript:location.href='delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>';" value="&laquo; Back" />
    <hr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Lots of ways really, hope it helps

Comment: np, check last edit for `.'\';` it was `.';\'` which is wrong